# Playing PCM with AudioTrack is a little noisy

Tags: android, endianness, gsm, pcm, audiotrack

Im getting audio data in `GSM` bytearray from server socket and I'm using [this](https://github.com/Metaswitch/fmj/blob/master/src/org/rubycoder/gsm/GSMDecoder.java) GSMDecoder to decode it to `PCM` and play. The decoder takes gsm data in byte array of length `33` and returns int array of length `160`.

First of all (in for loop) I have chopped the GSM bytearray to length of 33 and gave it to the decoder. The returned value from decoder is pcm int array, then I have added each decoded chunk (pcmChunk) to a custom InputStream named AudioStream:

```
 int x = 33; 

 //p is the GSM bytearray
 int len = p.length;

 byte[] gsmChunk;
 int[] pcmChunk;


 for (int i = 0; i < len - x + 1; i += x) {
      gsmChunk= Arrays.copyOfRange(p, i, i + x);
      pcmChunk= gsmDecoder.decode(gsmChunk);
      audioStream.addData(pcmChunk);
 }

 if (len % x != 0) {//end of array
      gsmChunk= Arrays.copyOfRange(p, len - len % x, len);
      pcmChunk= gsmDecoder.decode(gsmChunk);
      audioStream.addData(pcmChunk);
 }

 writeToAudioTrack(audioStream);
```

Then audioStream which contains the pcm data is being passed to method writeToAudioTrack() to play.

```
private void writeToAudioTrack(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    int i;
    byte[] s = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; //BUFFER_SIZE = 64

    while ((i = is.read(s, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > -1) {
        audioTrack.write(s, 0, i);

    }

}
```

AudioTrack has already been set:

```
    int sampleRate = 4200;
    int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

AudioStream.java:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class AudioStream extends InputStream {


    private ArrayList<Integer> pcm;


    public AudioStream() {
        pcm = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addData(int data[]){
        for(int i=0 ; i<data.length ; i++){
            pcm.add(data[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if(pcm.size()>0) {
            int r= pcm.remove(0);

            return (r>>4) & 0xFF;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The returned values in read() method of AudioStream:

```
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 247
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 249
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 252
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 0
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 3
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 247
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 241
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 249
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 6
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 11
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 5
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 249
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 242
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 249
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 5
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 9
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 3
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 247
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 244
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 252
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 3
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 6
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 0
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 252
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 252
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 0
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 1
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 255
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 253
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 252
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 254
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 1
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 5
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 3
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 254
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 0
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 3
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 2
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 4
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 2
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 253
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 253
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 0
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 3
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 10
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 5
12-17 18:59:20.788  : 250
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 250
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 253
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 2
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 12
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 6
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 248
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 248
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 2
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 9
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 19
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 13
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 249
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 244
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 254
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 8
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 15
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 9
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 249
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 245
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 252
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 7
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 14
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 11
12-17 18:59:20.793  : 253
```

And if I change r>>4 to r>>8 the result is more noisy:

```
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 252
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 255
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 0
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 255
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 0
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 255
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 4
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 250
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 0
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 4
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 4
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 0
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 252
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 255
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 4
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 4
12-17 19:21:36.043  : 0
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 250
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 255
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 4
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 5
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 249
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 3
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 5
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 3
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 253
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 251
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 2
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 3
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 1
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 0
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 254
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 255
12-17 19:21:36.048  : 255
```

I guess it's an endianness problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to [this decoder](https://github.com/steely-glint/pfhiaxdroid/tree/master/src/com/phonefromhere/android/codec/gsm) and now it's working just fine without any noises!